# Adapter pattern in C++, with non-virtual adapted methods

Tags: c++, polymorphism, adapter

I want to create an adapter class in C++, but the interface that I want to adapt to has several non-virtual methods. Can I still use the regular adapter pattern?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class  NewInterface{
    public:
      int methodA(){ cout << "A\n"; }
      virtual int methodB(){ cout << "B\n"; }
    };

    class OldInterface{
    public:
      int methodC(){ cout << "C\n"; }
      int methodD(){ cout << "D\n"; }
    };

    class Old2NewAdapter: public NewInterface {
    public:
      Old2NewAdapter( OldInterface* a ){ adaptee = a; }
      int methodA(){ return adaptee->methodC(); }
      int methodB(){ return adaptee->methodD(); }
    private:
      OldInterface* adaptee;
    };

    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
      NewInterface* NI = new Old2NewAdapter( new OldInterface() );
      NI->methodA();
      NI->methodB();
      return 0;
    }
```

If I have this setup, the output will be "A D" instead of "C D" as it should.

So how can I adapt OldInterface to NewInterface, without rewriting NewInterface so that all methods are virtual?

Comment: You could use [NVI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) to add a virtual function to `NewInterface` without changing the signature of `methodA` or use templates (static polymorphism).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, as I understand the description of NVI in the above link, I may still need to change the implementation of NewInterface even though I wouldn't have to change the methods to virtual. In my scenario, I cannot edit the implementation of NewInterface at all.

Comment: I fear it is impossible, unless you are able to manipulate the data 'methodA' is working on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you introduce another class? If you can then you can replace functions that use a `NewInterface` with an even `NewerInterface`:

```
class NewerInterface
{
public:
    int methodA()
    {
        // preconditions
        int const result = doMethodA();
        // postconditions
        return result;
    }

    int methodB()
    {
        // preconditions
        int const result = doMethodB();
        // postconditions
        return result;
    }

private:
    virtual int doMethodA() = 0;
    virtual int doMethodB() = 0;
};

class Old2NewerInterface : public NewerInterface
{
public:
    explicit Old2NewerInterface(OldInterface& x) : old_(&x)

private:
    virtual int doMethodA() { return old_->methodC(); }
    virtual int doMethodB() { return old_->methodD(); }

private:
    OldInterface* old_;
};

class New2NewerInterface : public NewerInterface
{
public:
    explicit New2NewerInterface(NewInterface& x) : new_(&x)

private:
    virtual int doMethodA() { return new_->methodA(); }
    virtual int doMethodB() { return new_->methodB(); }

private:
    NewInterface* new_;
};
```

Comment: No, not really. There is a lot of code that is written for NewInterface, that wouldn't work with NewerInterface. It is NewInterface that I need to somehow adapt to. I can always write converter code, to convert my old objects to new objects that are instances of "NewInterface", but I'd prefer to just change the interface without doing a lot of copying data. Still, if there is no clean way to accomplish that (making my OldInterface objects look like NewInterface objects), then converting them is also a viable way forward.

Comment: @Supernormal: Then as Dieter said, unless you can change what `methodA()` returns then you may just have to convert.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your input. Since no answer solves my problem, I am not sure how I can assign credit to your comments. But my solution will be to convert instead of adapt, and conclude that the Adapter design pattern doesn't work with C++, unless the target class of the adapter is declared with only virtual methods.